# Mac OS X PHP IDE with Git support

Tags: php, git, macos, ide

Can anyone suggest a PHP IDE (preferably built in Cocoa/ Objective-C, not Java) that also has native support or an excellent plugin for Git?

I am currently using NetBeans but I am not happy with the speed and the patchy Git plugin. I have previously used Zend Studio for a long time but that had stability issues.

Comment: I'm interested too in an answer! never found something nice... Tried Eclipse, netbeans, zend studio and aptana (based on eclipse)... But I'm not 100% satisfied.

Comment: Concerned by the [recent deprecation of Java on the mac](http://apple.slashdot.org/story/10/10/21/125222/Apple-Deprecates-Their-JVM?from=rss)?

Comment: @Alexandre-Jasmin yes I saw that this morning... I'm not too fussed I could always go back to TextMate without too much pain... it was triggered by yet more disaffection with NetBeans... @Bladedu completely agree!

Comment: Java being deprecated doesn't mean that you can't install it yourself. It's not like Apple is blocking it completely - they're just not pre-installing it for you.

Comment: @New-Stokes bit off topic but I understand the problem is with the GUI without Apple's VM the standard Java GUI screws up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextMate is my editor (ah.. no IDE) of choice. I use the GIT bundle and the Project+ plugin to see the directory structure etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) 2.0 is the stable version but I have been using the beta version 3.0 and love it

Comment: +1 As a long-time Aptana fan (still on 1.5, though), I'm itching to give 3.0 beta a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Komodo IDE for a few years now and think it's pretty great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any native PHP IDE for MacOSX.

However, I have been using RubyMine since its first public release, and I'm really happy with it. I would suggest you to try [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), the PHP-equivalent.
The GIT plugin is awesome.

Comment: No native? That's a shame... let's hope someone else knows of one... downloading for evaluation now... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Older post but I'll throw in my 2 cents.

All I really want is something that has great support for ruby/rails and php, and first class git support. It's quite hard to find actually.

I like Netbeans but no native git support is a killer. Even though it was a touted feature for version 7, it's nowhere to be seen even in 7 beta. Coda is nice but I find it lacks enough serious features to be a real development tool beyond the html with php sprinkled in crowd. Textmate, version 2 is some serious vaporware, and it's painfully slow on the occasion I attempt to load a remote project through a VPN. It's scanning large app directories on startup takes forever.

Then there's rubymine and phpstorm, which are nice, but then I'd have one IDE for ruby and one for php. Not exactly ideal... And of course most of these things are java anyway, which tend to be a little ugly and slow even if functional.

Realistically there's no good solution. For the longest time I've used skEdit since it had the bare features I needed. It has no git support, but at least it's native and fast, and one of the few editors I found that supports SFTP remote projects. Lately I've been using Aptana Studio 3 a bit more and I'm iffy on it. I love the git support, it's fantastic, and the built in ruby/rails tools are exceptional. Works quite well with php as well. However it's still a big java app, and the launch and shutdown times are a bit annoying, not to mention it can be a bit laggy at times... But so far, from what I've seen if you're looking for one IDE with good git support for web languages, Aptana 3 is probably the best bet...